# How to enable Eclipselink's static weaving from Gradle

Tags: java, ant, gradle, eclipselink

I'd like to enable Eclipselink's static weaving for my JPA classes from Gradle. The Eclipselink docs explain how to do this in an Ant task:

```
<target name="define.task" description="New task definition for EclipseLink static weaving"/>

<taskdef name="weave" classname="org.eclipse.persistence.tools.weaving.jpa.StaticWeaveAntTask"/>
</target>
<target name="weaving" description="perform weaving" depends="define.task">
    <weave  source="c:\myjar.jar"
            target="c:\wovenmyjar.jar"
            persistenceinfo="c:\myjar-containing-persistenceinfo.jar">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="c:\myjar-dependent.jar"/>
        </classpath>

    </weave>
</target>
```

Now I've got 2 questions:

**1. How do I 'translate' this into a Gradle approach?**
I've tried this (based on the docs at http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/ant.html#N1143F):

```
task eclipseWeave << {
    ant.taskdef(name: "weave",
                classname: "org.eclipse.persistence.tools.weaving.jpa.StaticWeaveAntTask",
                classpath: configurations.compile.asPath)

    ant.weave(source: relativePath(compileJava.destinationDir),
              target: relativePath(compileJava.destinationDir),
              persistenceinfo: relativePath(processResources.destinationDir) {
    }
}
```

but the problem is that the classpath doesn't seem to work within `ant.weave(..)`. The weaving process is aborted after a bit with the message:

```
Execution failed for task ':eclipseWeave'.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: some/class/from/my/dependencies
```

The classpath setting works for `ant.taskdef(..)` since the StaticWeaveAntTask is found in my dependencies. How can I make it apply to `ant.weave(..)` itself?

**2. How do I integrate this into my build, so it is executed automatically after each `compileJava` step?**

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question, but based on the OP's comment for the "gradle" way to do it, I thought I'd share our approach. We are using the JavaExec task and the various available configuration objects.

Since the weaving is done in the classes directory (before the JAR is built) you end up only having to build one jar, not two. Since our jar is quite large, that was important to us.

```
task performJPAWeaving(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: "compileJava"){
  inputs.dir compileJava.destinationDir
  outputs.dir compileJava.destinationDir
  main "org.eclipse.persistence.tools.weaving.jpa.StaticWeave"
  args  "-persistenceinfo",
   "src/main/resources",
   compileJava.destinationDir.getAbsolutePath()
  classpath = configurations.compileClasspath
}

tasks.withType(Jar){
  dependsOn "performJPAWeaving"
}
```

Comment: 'Compile' is not available in newer releases of Gradle. It is named 'JavaCompile' now.

Comment: @Terence, the use of `execute` is [discouraged](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/static-weaving-with-eclipselink-broken-with-gradle-4-2-1/24354). `Project.javaexec` is recommended instead.

Comment: @smoothreggae - Yup, it certainly looks like that's now the case! We actually moved away from calling .execute() a while back and just make it a jar task dependency. I'll update the answer to show that.

Comment: This should use `classpath = configurations.compileClasspath` in order to work; also it seems that both source and target directories are required. Check class documentation of `StaticWeave` class.

Comment: @cheppsn It looks like `compileClasspath` is, indeed, more correct than `compile` (https://discuss.gradle.org/t/sourcesets-main-compileclasspath-vs-configurations-compile/6782). While they are both usually the same, `compileClasspath` is definitely the way to go. And, I think you just missed the last argument in the example because it wasn't quoted like the others. The example has always included the target, it wouldn't have worked with out it :-).

Answer (score 1):

### Problem description

I had a similar issue and would like to share my solution which is based on the previous post. Following problems were solved:

- Process *persistence.xml* and replace tokens before weaving.
- Find a workaround for this known [EclipseLink Weaver bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=295031) which prevents using the Weavers *-persistenceunit* flag with Gradle.
- Discover entitiy classes automatically instead of listing them in *persistence.xml*.

### Step 1: Process persistence.xml

Firstly, the placeholder **@datasourceName@** should be replaced with an **actual value**. This is achieved through following snipped in your build.gradle file:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

ext {
    dsName = 'MyDataSourceName'
    puName = 'MyPuName'
}

processResources {
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
        datasourceName: dsName,
        persistenceUnitName: puName
    ])
}
```

Following code shows the (simplified) *src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml* file:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="@datasourceName@" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=@datasourceName@)</jta-data-source>

    <!-- Necessary to let EclipseLink/Weaver discover local classes without listing them in this file,
        see http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/concepts/app_dev001.htm#BGBHFFAG-->
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <!-- Tell the application container that our classes are already woven,
            see https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving-->
        <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

It's important to mention, that the flag **exclude-unlisted-classes** must be set to **false** in order to make the EclipseLink Weaver discovering
the annotated entity classes automatically. Make also sure, that the property "**eclipselink.weaving**" is set to "**static**" which tells your
application runtime, that the entity classes are already woven and do not need to be enhanced dynamically. If you work with OSGi, keep in mind to import
all necessary EclipseLink packages into the bundle which contains the woven classes.

After the **processResources** task has been executed, the generated file *build/resources/main/META-INF/persistence.xml* looks like this (note the persistence-unit name):

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="MyPuName" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=MyDataSourceName)</jta-data-source>

    <!-- Necessary to let EclipseLink/Weaver discover local classes without listing them in this file, 
      see http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/concepts/app_dev001.htm#BGBHFFAG -->
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <!-- Tell the application container that our classes are already woven,
            see, https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving-->
        <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

### Step 2: Copy the generated persistence.xml

Next, we add a new **Copy** task which copies the processed resources into the output directory of the **compileJava** task. This is necessary
to have all necessary artifacts on the Weavers classpath (works around bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=295031). Add
following task to your *build.gradle* file:

```
task copyResourcesToClassesOutputDir(type: Copy, dependsOn: processResources) {
    from processResources.destinationDir
    into compileJava.destinationDir
}
```

### Step 3: Weave your entity classes

In order to enhance your classes, it's necessary to configure your build appropriately. Add following snipped to your *build.gradle*. A separate classpath configuration has been declared because having the EclipseLink classes in the ordinary compile classpath is not desired.

```
configurations {
    providedApi
}

dependencies {
    providedApi 'org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa:2.7.2'
    providedApi 'org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.2.0'
}

task performJPAWeaving(type: JavaExec) {
    main "org.eclipse.persistence.tools.weaving.jpa.StaticWeave"
    args "-loglevel",
        "FINE",
        compileJava.destinationDir.absolutePath,
        compileJava.destinationDir.absolutePath

    classpath (configurations.compile, configurations.providedApi)

    dependsOn compileJava
    dependsOn copyResourcesToClassesOutputDir
}

// Do always weave the classes before a JAR is created
tasks.withType(Jar) {
    dependsOn "performJPAWeaving"
}
```

That's it! If you run now any **Jar** task, your entity classes will be enhanced before they are packed into the Jar file.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me very well (possibly because of changes to Gradle - I'm using v7.4). I ended up copying my persistence.xml (with `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>` in it) into my classes directory and then running the EclipseLink Weaver. I put it as part for `doLast` for the Java Compile which I think will allow Gradle to cache compilation in the normal way (although I'm not fully clear on this) - the alternative is before the Jar task but I want to make sure that local behaviour is identical to deployed behaviour for things like lazy loading.

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    doLast {
        def path = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
        def listOfUrls = path.collect {f -> f.toURI().toURL()} as URL[]
        def loader = new URLClassLoader(listOfUrls)

        //Finding classes only works from the root containing persistence.xml containing directory downwards
        def xmlContents = new File(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs.iterator().next(), 'META-INF/persistence.xml').text
        def tempDir = new File(sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs.singleFile, 'META-INF')
        tempDir.mkdirs()
        def tempFile = new File(tempDir, 'persistence.xml')
        tempFile.delete()
        tempFile << xmlContents
        xmlContents = null

        def proc = new org.eclipse.persistence.tools.weaving.jpa.StaticWeaveProcessor(
                sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs.singleFile,
                sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs.singleFile
        )
        proc.setLogLevel(5)
        proc.setClassLoader(loader)
        proc.setPersistenceInfo(sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs.singleFile)
        proc.performWeaving()

        tempFile.delete()
        tempDir.delete()
    }
}
```

You also have to have `org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa` as a script dependency - for me that meant adding it to `buildSrc/build.gradle` but for others it might mean adding a `classpath` entry to your `buildscript` dependencies like you do with Legacy plugins.

I'm not happy with how I find the persistence.xml file - I'm sure there's a better way but it works for me for now and I've spent too long on this!

Comment: mjaggard, I was unable to import org.eclipse.persistence.tools.weaving.jpa.StaticWeaveProcessor even after adding local jars as dependencies. Do you mind sharing code snippet of how you added jars to classpath?

Comment: Annoyingly this breaks the incremental build so although up-to-date works, the whole source folder gets recompiled.

Comment: @Ramu I am using a Gradle conventions plugin so I have `implementation 'org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa:2.7.9'` in the `dependencies` section of my build.gradle for the plugin plus the same in my build.gradle for the actual project.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late to the party but this is possible very easily with Gradle, you just need to think it through.

There are 3 steps to do in order to make this work:

- Copy the persistence.xml file into the source folder next to the classes
- Do the weaving
- Remove the `persistence.xml` file from the classes source folder to avoid duplicate `persistence.xml` conflicts on the classpath

Also, it's very important to hook the process up into the compileJava task's last step in order to not break Gradle's up-to-date check, otherwise you can end up in a situation where Gradle will always recompile your code no matter nothing has changed.

For a more detailed explanation, check out my article on it: [EclipseLink static weaving with Gradle](https://arnoldgalovics.com/eclipselink-static-weaving-gradle/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=eclipselink-static-weaving-gradle).

Comment: This works with up-to-date checks but still breaks the incremental build.

Answer (score 0):

In kts it should be something like this, also did some special change in the code so it can [handle configuration cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/configuration_cache.html#config_cache:requirements) as well. This should work for incremental build as well.

```kotlin
interface A {
    @get:Inject
    val fs: FileSystemOperations

    @get:Inject
    val exec: ExecOperations
}

tasks.withType<JavaCompile>().configureEach {
    val mainSS by sourceSets.main
    val classes = mainSS.output.classesDirs.singleFile
    val runtimeClasspath: FileCollection = configurations.runtimeClasspath.get()
    val (fs, exec) = objects.newInstance<A>().let { it.fs to it.exec }

    doLast {
        fs.copy {
            from("src/main/resources/META-INF/")
            into("${classes}/META-INF/")
        }
        exec.javaexec {
            description = "Performs EclipseLink static weaving of entity classes"
            mainClass = "org.eclipse.persistence.tools.weaving.jpa.StaticWeave"
            // The weaving will be performed in place if source and target point to the same location.
            args = listOf(
                "-persistenceinfo",
                classes.toString(),
                "-classpath",
                runtimeClasspath.asPath,
                classes.toString(),
                classes.toString()
            )
            classpath = runtimeClasspath
        }
        fs.delete {
            delete("${classes}/META-INF/")
        }
    }
}
```